# Can I loop throught my program with different sets of variables read from excel rows?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, switch-statement, apache-poi

Quick Summary: Each Excel row is for a different personal project, so each row contains different values for items such as `homepageURL` `fromEmail` and `toEmail`. I need to iterate through each row in turn, then use it's values as variables in my program (take screenshots of page elements, then email them out).

I have the code written to take the screenshots and email them, But must I have it in my program multiple times, for each time I iterate through a new Excel Row (thus getting new variables)? It world be much preferable to have something like this

1. Import Row 1 variables using POI
2. Run through the program using those variables
3. Import Row 2 variables (Redeclare the same variables maybe?)
4. Run through the same code using those variables.

I am not sure how helpful my code is. Right now, it just reads Row 1, stores the cells as variables, then runs the program for THOSE variables.

```
    public class ExcelReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {                
    {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/username/Desktop/JiraScreens/Dashboards.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        XSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(0);
        XSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((int) 0);
        String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((int) 1);
        String b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellC1 = row1.getCell((int) 2);
        String c1Val = cellC1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellD1 = row1.getCell((int) 3);
        String d1Val = cellD1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellE1 = row1.getCell((int) 4);
        String e1Val = cellE1.getStringCellValue();
        XSSFCell cellF1 = row1.getCell((int) 5);
        String f1Val = cellF1.getStringCellValue();
    //this is my program
    public void captureImages () throws IOException {
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need, is a loop.
Java supports for, do - while and while loops.

More info is available here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

You have to find a way to find out how many rows does you Excel document contain, then use a loop to iterate over each row and process it accordingly.